# Deleting rows where ID in #tempTable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Why can't I do this:

```
declare @myTempTableList TABLE (
CommId int
)
insert into @myTempTableList (CommId)
VALUES 
(742), (803)

delete from myRealTable where MyRealTableId in (
    select mrt.MyRealTableId from MyRealTable mrt
    where commId in (@myTempTableList)
)
```

It tells me that I must declare the scalar variable @myTempTableList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from myRealTable where MyRealTableId in (
    select mrt.MyRealTableId from MyRealTable mrt
    where commId in (SELECT CommId FROM @myTempTableList)
)
```

Try the above

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM myRealTable 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM  @myTempTableList
              WHERE myRealTable.MyRealTableId  = @myTempTableList.CommId)
```